# Grabar camara con javascript en ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, programación-móvil

Alguien me puede ayudar, estoy tratando hacer que javascript grabe la camara en iphone, el codigo ya funciona en todas las plataformas menos en esa, alguien que sepa de alguna funcion que me permita grabar, gracias

```
startBtn.addEventListener('click',function() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraint).then(function(stream) {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: 'video/webM'
        });
        recorder.start();
    }).catch(function(err) {
        alert('imposible '+err);
    });
    
})
```

El "err" cuando lo uso en iphone me sale como error ReferenceError: Cant't find variable: MediaRecorder

Comment: ¿en qué navegador? ¿podrías agregarlo a la pregunta?